# notify-send does nothing, yet, libnotify is installed

Tags: libnotify

I am trying to use notify-send, but it doesn't display.

I am reasonably sure I have the correct packages installed, but I am not expert in configuring the notification settings.

I know I have some sort of notification package working - I get notifications from Pidgin (sporadically).

What is the correct configuration for notify-send to operate correctly?

- I have `libnotify-bin` installed
- I have the `notification-daemon` installed

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are no special configuration files as far as I know so I would try and reinstall the package

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install libnotify-bin notify-osd
```

Comment: You don't have to reinstall the two packages separately, but can do so with a single command: `sudo apt-get --reinstall install libnotify-bin notify-osd`

Comment: Under Debian Wheezy I need also start notification daemon like **/usr/lib/notify-osd/notify-osd**

Comment: I also discover **notification-daemon** under Debian which have nicer look.

Comment: For arch users: `pacman -Rnsdd libnotify && pacman -Sy libnotify`

Comment: @gavenkoa **THANKS** it solved my problem! Gosh `GOLD` for you! :D

Comment: @gavenkoa can you please add that as an additional answer, just because I found it so incredibly helpful! `thanks`! ️

Answer (score 5):

In my case, the notification was not displayed because I had netbeans in full screen mode in the background.

For some weird reason, the message was getting hidden.

Comment: Strange. Had the same problem with a terminal running full screen trying this. Making it a window magically fixes it.

Comment: I had the same with PHPStorm, thanks for commenting as it was confusing me as to why it wasn't working.

Comment: Same thing but with emacs on full-screen, strange.

Answer (score 3):

In my case is because of I accidentally disable **Notification Banners** settings.

[image]

Note that this answer might not relevant to OP case which claims that Pidgin is working. But it should help someone based on the question title.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, it only works with a zero time limit (`-t 0`) or with critical urgency (`-u critical`).

```bsh
notify-send -t 0 "Nagging you."
notify-send -u critical "It's critical"
```

Comment: If you have xfce4-notifyd installed and it is happening to you, then open xfce4-notifyd-config and go to applications and let allowed the notify-send entry.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install `libnotify-bin` to be able to use the "notify-send" command.

Comment: It's been installed.

Comment: @Paul: then it should work... I am sure that's the required package to be able to use notify-send, unless something is wrong with libnotify on your system.

Answer (score 0):

little hint:

From:
[[https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-notifier/+bug/300463]](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-notifier/+bug/300463%5d)

> As described in http://forum.lxde.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=114&p=287 the update-notifier daemon is not run automatically on other desktops who support it, so I don't get automatic updates as specified in the configuration unless I manually run the update-manager (which works alright).
>
> In:
>
> ```
>    /etc/xdg/autostart/update-notifier.desktop
> ```
>
> There is a line inside this file read like this:
>
> ```
>    OnlyShowIn=GNOME;XFCE;
> ```
>
> This line should be changed to:
>          NotShowIn=KDE;
>   Or other unsupported desktops.
>
> I'm using Xubuntu 8.10 and the LXDE desktop environment (that's how I found out)