# notify-send only works as root (via sudo)

Tags: notification, libnotify

I have notify-send and all the requirments installed, but when I run a simple command

```
notify-send "Test" "Test Message"
```

nothing happens, but if I run the same command through sudo, it works.

System processes can send notifications with no problem, so I see a popup when I join a new wireless LAN, for example.

What group do I need to be a member of in order to send notifications?

Answer (score 0):

Check the owner of the `notify-osd` process:

`ps -e -o fname,user | grep notify-o`

On my system, it is the current user. If it is not, try killing the process and restart it as current user.

Comment: No, notify-osd is running as me.

Comment: Are any of the following questions related?

http://askubuntu.com/questions/16173/notify-osd-stops-working-after-totem-has-been-running-for-a-while

http://askubuntu.com/questions/52960/notify-send-does-nothing-yet-libnotify-is-installed

Comment: No, I have all the deps installed and AFAIK, I have nothing inhibiting the screensaver, it does indeed start after a period of inactivity. The fact I can run it as root just makes it feel like a problem with permissions.

Comment: Well, other people have problems running it as `root`... http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1727148

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that there are too notifications acumulated.
if you try notification-properties > prewiew. It tells you. You should restart notification-daemon:

```
sudo killall notification-daemon
/usr/lib/notification-daemon/notification-daemon
```